# Difference between INSERT and COPY

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

As per the documentation,

Loading large number of rows using COPY is always faster than using INSERT, even if PREPARE is used and multiple insertions are batched into a single transaction.

Why COPY is faster than INSERT (multiple insertion are batched into single transaction) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quite a number of reasons, actually, but the main ones are:

- Typically, client applications wait for confirmation of one `INSERT`'s success before sending the next. So there's a round-trip delay for each `INSERT`, scheduling delays, etc. (PgJDBC supports pipelineing `INSERT`s in batches, but I'm not aware of any other clients that do).
- Each `INSERT` has to go through the whole executor. Use of a prepared statement bypasses the need to run the parser, rewriter and planner, but there's still executor state to set up and tear down for each row. `COPY` does some setup once, and has an *extremely* low overhead for each row, especially where no triggers are involved.

The first point is the most significant. It's all about network round-trips and rescheduling delays.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `COPY` is a single statement, while each `INSERT` is a separate statement. Since each single statement is normally subject to logging ([manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/wal-configuration.html)), even inside a unique transaction, the use of many `INSERT` is slower than the use of a single `COPY`.