# Postgres Insert statements from stdin

Tags: sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

I have a dump file which is:

```
COPY public.applications (id, reference_id, lead_id) FROM stdin;
```

This is followed by the rows that need to be added.

Instead of copy, I want to insert these rows from stdin because copy is replacing my entire table (removing existing data in the table). I just want to add rows, not remove any existing ones.

I tried:

```
insert into public.applications (id, reference_id, lead_id) values FROM stdin;
```

But this is incorrect syntax. Whats the correct way to do this?
Is there a way to tweak the copy command to only add rows and not replace the table?

Comment: `copy` does not removed existing rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently pointed out in the comments, `copy` does not do replacements. 
Which is to say, `COPY public.applications (id, reference_id, lead_id) FROM stdin;`
 will emulate same behaviour as insert.

Comment: Whats the difference then between insert and copy?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043420/difference-between-insert-and-copy