# Using Spring boot JdbcTemplate for copy?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I came across this question in StackOverflow:

[Difference between INSERT and COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043420/difference-between-insert-and-copy)

and was wondering if spring boots `jdbcTemplate`  can be used for a copy instead of insert.

I see a `jdbcTemplate.update` but that does insert/update.

Comment: Why would that be limited to insert and update only? What makes you think it is?

Comment: @M.Deinum <https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html> says it does single update and batch updates. I couldnt find any where it saying COPY is supported

Comment: It supports modifying statements, so if you put a COPY or UPSERT or .. in there it will work if your db supports it.

Comment: or you could use  org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager